# why cannot center an element that set position as absolute by using left and right 0

Tags: css

I want to center all items within the contacts class

```css
.contacts {
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 37px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.contact-card {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.contacts .contact-card img {
  width: 225px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div className="contacts">
  <div className="contact-card">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/357f94/00ff04" />
    <h3>Mr.Whiskerson</h3>
    <div className="info-group">
      <i className="fa-solid fa-phone"></i>
      <p>(212) 555-1234</p>
    </div>
    <div className="info-group">
      <i className="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
      <p>MrWhiskerson.meow</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

when I set as position left 0 and right 0 nothing is change how can I do this using position absolute

Answer (score -1):

Just use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) property (or Grid) to center elements.

I'll add in your code `display:flex` to the main container, and set `justify-content: center;` to center it's child horizontally (Jusitfy-content defines the alignment along the main axis).

```css
.contacts {
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 37px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: aqua;
  display:flex;/* add */
  justify-content:center; /* add */
}

.contact-card {
  /*position: absolute; remove
  left: 0;
  right: 0;*/
}



.contacts .contact-card img {
  width: 225px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="contacts">
  <div class="contact-card">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/357f94/00ff04" />
    <h3>Mr.Whiskerson</h3>
    <div class="info-group">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i>
      <p>(212) 555-1234</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info-group">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
      <p>MrWhiskerson.meow</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

If you want to use `position:absolute` instead you can do this way

```css
.contacts {
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 37px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.contact-card {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; 
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.contacts .contact-card img {
  width: 225px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="contacts">
  <div class="contact-card">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/357f94/00ff04" />
    <h3>Mr.Whiskerson</h3>
    <div class="info-group">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i>
      <p>(212) 555-1234</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info-group">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
      <p>MrWhiskerson.meow</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: this works but do you know why it does not work when position absolute

Comment: Because you use it in the wrong mode. For example you can set left:50% and then use transform:translateX(-50%); But remeber that position:absolute remove elements from normal flow